# write down functions in terms of complex coordinate $z=x+iy$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Indentifying $\Bbb R^2$ with the complex plane $\Bbb C$ via the map $(x,y)→ x+iy$, write down the following functions in terms of complex coordinate $z = x + iy$.

i) the translation by the vector (1,2)

ii) a rotation anticlockwise by $\theta$

iii) a reflection in the x-axis

iv) reflection in the line $y=x+10$

v) reflection in the line $y=x$

vi) inversion in the circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius r

Here are my answers, I am just looking for verification. Thanks!

ANSWERS:

i) $t(z) = z + 1 + 2i$

ii) $t(z) = e^{i\theta}z$

iii) $t(z) = \overline z$

iv) ?

v) ?

vi) ?

Comment: for i), I would say $t(z)=z+1+2i$

Comment: yes! this is what I meant.. I wrote down the wrong answer. It has been changed now. Thank you.

Comment: What is v)? It seems to be missing

Comment: changed! it has been edited, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what a reflection about the line $y = x+10$ means.  For instance, the point $(0,10)$ is on the line and gets mapped to the same point.  Similarly, the point $(1,11)$ stays where it is.  So the point $(1,10)$ would be mapped to $(0,11)$ and vice versa.  What kind of transformation does this?  Well, in general, it seems that you would want to take flip the $x$- and $y$-values, and then add $(-10,10)$; i.e., $$(x,y) \mapsto (y-10,x+10).$$

Well, while the above works, it seems to lack some rigor.  So let's think about this more methodically.  You may note that the reflection about the line $y = x$ is just $$(x,y) \mapsto (y,x).$$  So if we do a translation of $y = x+10$ by $(0,-10)$, followed by the reflection, then another translation back by $(0,10)$, we have the composition of mappings $$(x,y) \mapsto (x,y-10) \mapsto (y-10,x) \mapsto (y-10,x+10),$$ which is what we found earlier.

How do we write this transformation in terms of complex numbers?  We clearly want $$z = x + yi \mapsto (y-10) + (x+10)i.$$  But is there a function of $z$ that does this?  Well, one way is to observe $$z + \bar z = (x+yi)+(x-yi) = 2x, \\ z - \bar z = (x+yi)-(x-yi) = 2yi,$$ so that $$(y-10) + (x+10)i = \left(\frac{z - \bar z}{2i} - 10 \right) + \left(\frac{z + \bar z}{2} + 10\right)i = -10 + (\bar z + 10)i.$$

I will skip the next part and go to the last.  Note that inversion in the circle with radius $r$ requires that $$|t(z)||z| = r^2,$$ that is to say, the product of the magnitudes of the inverted point and the original point must equal the square of the radius.  Moreover, we must also have $$\arg(t(z)) = \arg(z),$$ meaning their angles remain the same.  So if $$z = |z|e^{i\arg(z)},$$ what is $t(z)$?

Comment: for iv) $t(z) = \overline z i +10i -10$ and for v) $t(z) = \overline z i $. I am still unsure of the last one..

Comment: is it $t(z) = r^2 / \overline z$

Comment: $$t(z) = |t(z)|e^{i \arg(t(z))} = \frac{r^2}{|z|}e^{i \arg(z)}$$ from the requirements in my answer.  Then note $$|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$ and $$e^{i \arg(z)} = \cos \arg(z) + i \sin \arg(z) = \cos \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + i \sin \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}.$$  But since $$\cos \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$ we can write this as $$t(z) = r^2 \frac{z}{|z|^2},$$ which in retrospect should be obvious.

Comment: thank you so much. It makes a lot more sense now.